# ¿Por qué no continúa el push?

Tags: git, git-push

¿por qué no continúa el push al master?
Antes me dio un error y decidí cambiar el buffer de git del por defect 1MiB a 500MiB. No funcionó y le puse 1 GiB y ahora no continúa (antes tampoco).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]